# Replace all instances of a variable referenced in VB code based on condition

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters

so recently with help I got to the point of using the output parameter of a sql stored procedure in a vb code,this is a follow up question on how to reference and replace a output parameter based on a condition, now the issue is I am trying to replace all instances of that variable in the code based on a IF condition.

The code I am using below generates the value I want to append based on the condition:

```
 Dim DocName As String
 DocName = drDocDetailData("DocName").ToString         

 Using DocDetail As New SqlCommand
 With DocDetail
      .Connection = con
      .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
      .CommandText = ("up_AddDocumentSuffix")
      .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName", con)
      .Parameters.Add("@DocSuffix", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
      .ExecuteNonQuery()
      suffix = DocDetail.Parameters("@DocSuffix").Value
      Docname = sb.Append(DocName).Append(suffix).ToString()
End With
End Using
```

Now I have this docname parameter referenced throughout the VB code in different sections:

```
 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName",   Trim(drDocDetailData("DocName").ToString))
```

I want to replace it with the DocName appended value in the first code only if the client is this specific client (client name = "company1"), is there any way to replace a certain parameter in the entire code based on a condition?

Comment: Get client information first, then use your `If` condition and replace value before executing stored procedures

Comment: @Fabio but then when for the IF..THEN section for the THEN section would I need to copy and paste the entire procedure if its not that client?

Comment: As  I understand it is enough to change parameter

Comment: @Fabio I am sorry I dont understand can you elaborate?